# xmlstarlet: get exact value

Tags: batch-file, command-line, xmlstarlet

input:

```
  <ReferenceTitle>
    <TitleText>Mozart - Don Giovanni</TitleText>
  </ReferenceTitle>
```

my code:

```
for /R %%a in (*.xml) do (
    for /f %%i in ('%root%\files\xml.exe sel -v "/ernm:NewReleaseMessage/ResourceList/SoundRecording/ReferenceTitle/TitleText[1]" %%a') do set titel=%%i
    )
```

I would like to get the exact (entire) value of  using XML-starlet, however all i'm getting is 'Mozart '. What am I missing?

Comment: With xmlstarlet for Linux: `xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//TitleText" file.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Try `for /f "delims=" %%i in etc...` otherwise the default delimiter is a space, hence you only get the first word. The `/f "delims="` option says there is no delimiter and you get the whole line. Type `for /?` for more details.